Trying to compare user input with text file data, not finding the user input in the text file
Currently writing a program where the user can login with an account username and password. The user input for the username and password is written to a dictionary (account_login) which is then compared with the username and passwords that are in the text file.
Here is the code where the issue lies:
def login_fn():
    print("Please enter your account details below.")
    current_usrname = input("Username: >")
    current_pswrd = input("Password: >")
    account_login.update({current_usrname:current_pswrd})
    with open('accounts.txt', 'r') as file:
        file.readlines()
        if account_login in file:
            print("logged in!")
        else:
            print("invalid!")

Here is the text file just for reference:
fredsmart1,1234567890
jrobertson4,r@=%8(_W=1
bob101,1234598abc
marcusw,3#tr@9dw%4
popeyedd,1989eidjce
junkman00,p3*(kd8&ld
sbj2021,$d5e(ep2(de4ab3
robotman,7777Spy007

My issue is that it keeps coming back saying that it couldn't find the username and password entered by the user even if it's in the text file.
I would enter in the robotman account, for instance, and it will return with the string "Invalid!" meaning that it couldn't find that account in the text file.
I am trying to get it to return with "logged in!" meaning that it found the account.
Still pretty new to python, any help is appreciated!

Did these answers solve your problem?


Never ever store passwords in plain text for any purpose other than education.
Don't input password in plain text, use getpass.
Read and process file line by line.
Match the correct pattern with file line (don't forget to strip newline character).
Assuming passwords can contain commas, split line on first comma (credits to @SamR).

What was incorect:

Matching to file object instead of file content.
Matching dict to string is impossible.

from getpass import getpass

def login():
    print("Please enter your account details below.")
    username = input("Username: ")
    password = getpass("Password: ")
    logged_in = False
    with open('accounts.txt') as file:
        for line in file:
            if line.strip().split(',', 1) == [username, password]:
                logged_in = True
    if logged_in:
        print("logged in!")
    else:
        print("invalid!")


awesome, thanks so much! yep obviously i would never put actual account information into a text document, this program is for a class and a requirement is for me to put account info into a provided text file. this was very helpful, thanks a ton!

Glad to hear that! When you decided on the preferred answer, could you please select one to mark your question as answered.

The way this answer compares the username and password together means passwords with commas in can be entered incorrectly and the credentials still accepted. For example if my username was samr and my password 01234,567, I could successfully log in by entering the username samr01234 and password 567. May not be a huge concern in practice but is worth noting - particularly if this is for a class @gorillaTime45 is taking.

@SamR this is the problem of the storage format, it is for learning purpose only.

@makukha agreed - it would be better to use a separator that could not appear in passwords. But in the absence of that, if you were to make the not ludicrous assumption that usernames cannot have commas in and passwords can then you could split on the first comma and compare usernames and passwords separately.

@SamR I agree, this will improve the answer.

The issue lies in how you comparing account_login dictionaryy with contents of file. You are currently reading all lines from file but not actually comparing input with each line properly.
You should:

Read full content line by line
Split each line by comma to separate passwords and usernames
Compare user input with these values

def login_fn():
    print("Please enter your account details below.")
    current_usrname = input("Username: >")
    current_pswrd = input("Password: >")
    with open('accounts.txt','r') as file:
        for line in file:
            stored_usrname, stored_pswrd = line.strip().split(',')
            if current_usrname == stored_usrname and current_pswrd == stored_pswrd:
                print("logged in!")
                return
    print("invalid!")


Open and process the username/password file once only and keep its contents in a dictionary.
Then all you need to do is get the username/password and compare with what's in the dictionary.
An empty input will cause the loop to break.
FILENAME = "accounts.txt"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open(FILENAME) as accounts:
        account_login = dict(e.rstrip().split(",") for e in accounts)
    while username := input("Username: "):
        password = input("Password: ")
        if account_login.get(username) == password:
            print("Logged in")
        else:
            print("Invalid")

